# Group by, deriving only one data set and more than one dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a table as follows

```
StudentID    Name  Subject
1            AAA   Computers
2            BBB   Computers
2            BBB   Electronics
3            CCC   Electronics
```

I want load this data, into two tables as below
OnlyOneSubject Table

```
StudentID    Name  Subject
1            AAA   Computers
3            CCC   Electronics
```

MoreThanOneSubject Table

```
StudentID    Name  Subject
2            BBB   Computers
2            BBB   Electronics
```

My sql as below, not sure how to extract data from this below query.

```
 SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by Name order by Subject) FROM 
 STUDENTS
```

Comment: But it is so much better in one table.  Why would you want to split the data up?

Comment: My Problem is not exactly this, it is similar, once i get into this more than one subjects kind then i have to apply some cleansing rules and make it only one row and combine it to first data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
WITH STUDENTS(StudentID,Name,Subject)AS(
   SELECT 1,'AAA','Computers' UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2,'BBB','Computers' UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2,'BBB','Electronics' UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3,'CCC','Electronics'
)
select * from (
   SELECT *,count(0) over(partition by Name) as cnt FROM STUDENTS
) as t where cnt=1  ---or cnt>1 for MoreThanOneSubject
```

```
StudentID   Name    Subject cnt
1   AAA Computers   1
3   CCC Electronics 1
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first one...

```
select *
from table
where StudentID in (select StudentID from table group by StudentID having count(*) = 1)
```

And the second one...

```
select *
from table
where StudentID in (select StudentID from table group by StudentID having count(*) > 1)
```

But I'd really only use this to return results... no need to divide a table that'd you have to constantly update.